# Find the minimum value of $\frac{1}{x - y} + \frac{1}{y - z} + \frac{1}{x - z}$ for real numbers $x > y > z$ given $(x - y)(y - z)(x - z) = 17$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

I've tried using AM-GM inequality:

$$
\frac1{x-y}+\frac1{y-z}+\frac1{x-z}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac1{(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)}}
$$
Which gives us
$$
\frac1{x-y}+\frac1{y-z}+\frac1{x-z}\ge\frac3{\sqrt[3]{17}}
$$
By plugging in the value.

I thought I was done. However, the equality holds if and only if $\frac1{x-y}=\frac1{y-z}=\frac1{x-z}$
This never happens because $x > y > z$. The inequality turns out to be strict.
Therefore, the minimum value is  greater than $\frac3{\sqrt[3]{17}}$

Can someone provide a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You might find it easier to let $a=x-y$, $b=y-z$ both positive, find $a$ in terms of $b$, then find $b$ which maximises the expression and thus the maximum of the expression.  You may have to solve a cubic equation on the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x > y > z$, It seems natural to me to write
$$x - z > y - z > 0$$
hence let $$a = y-z, \quad b = x-y, \quad a+b = x-z.$$
Then we wish to minimize
$$f(a,b) = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{a+b}$$
subject to the constraints $$ab(a+b) = 17, \quad a, b > 0.$$
So $$f(a,b) = \frac{a(a+b) + b(a+b) + ab}{ab(a+b)} = \frac{a^2 + b^2 + 3ab}{17}.$$
Can you now minimize $f(a,b)$ subject to the above constraints?

Hint:

> Write $$a^2 + b^2 + 3ab = (a^2 + 2ab + b^2) + ab = (a+b)^2 + ab = (a+b)^2 + \frac{17}{a+b}.$$  Now let $c = a+b$, so that $$f(a,b) = \frac{c^2}{17} + \frac{1}{c}$$ and minimize with respect to $c > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x-y=a$ and $y-z=b$.

Thus, $x-z=a+b$, the condition gives $ab(a+b)=17$ and we need to find a minimal value of $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a+b},$$ which for $$a=b=\sqrt[3]{\frac{17}{2}}$$ gives a value $\frac{5}{\sqrt[3]{68}}.$

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, after homogenization we need to prove that:
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a+b}\geq\frac{5}{\sqrt[3]{4(a+b)ab}}.$$
Now, let $a+b=2\sqrt{ab}x^3.$

Thus, by AM-GM $x\geq1$ and we need to prove that:
$$2x^3+\frac{1}{2x^3}\geq\frac{5}{2x}$$ or $$4x^6+1\geq5x^2,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$4x^6+1\geq5\sqrt[5]{\left(x^6\right)^4\cdot1}\geq5x^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve the problem using the method of Lagrange multipliers. With $x-y=a>0$ and $y-z=b>0$ (hence $x-z=a+b$), we want to minimize
$$
f(a,b)=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{a+b} \tag{1}
$$
subject to the constraint
$$
ab(a+b)=17. \tag{2}
$$
To solve this problem, let's find the stationary points of
$$
g(a,b,\lambda)=f(a,b)+\lambda[ab(a+b)-17], \tag{3}
$$
which are given by the solutions to the system of equations
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial a}=0&\implies -\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\lambda(2ab+b^2)=0, \tag{4a} \\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial b}=0&\implies -\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\lambda(a^2+2ab)=0, \tag{4b} \\
\end{align}
and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \lambda}=0$, which is equivalent to the constraint $(2)$.

Subtracting $(4\text{b})$ from $(4\text{a})$ we obtain
$$
-\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\lambda(b^2-a^2)=0 \implies
(b^2-a^2)\left(\lambda-\frac{1}{a^2b^2}\right)=0
$$
$$
\implies b^2=a^2\quad\text{or}\quad \lambda=\frac{1}{a^2b^2}. \tag{5}
$$
Let's examine these two possibilities:

1. $b^2=a^2$ implies $b=a$ (since $a$ and $b$ are both positive). Inserting this in $(2)$ and solving for $a$ we find $a=\sqrt[3]{\frac{17}{2}}$. The corresponding value of $f$ is
   $$
   f(a,a)=\frac{5}{2a}=\frac{5}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{17}}=\frac{5}{\sqrt[3]{64}}, \tag{6}
   $$
   which agrees with the result found by Michael Rozenberg.
2. Plugging $\lambda=\frac{1}{a^2b^2}$ into Eq. $(4\text{a})$ and simplifying, we obtain
   $$
   -\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{2}{ab}=0. \tag{7}
   $$
   Using Eq. $(2)$, we may rewrite $(7)$ as
   $$
   -\frac{1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{2(a+b)}{17}=0, \tag{8}
   $$
   which is equivalent to the solution presented by heropup$^{(*)}$. Solving $(8)$ we find $a+b=\sqrt[3]{\frac{17}{2}}$; Eqs. $(2)$ and $(1)$ then yield $ab=\sqrt[3]{2\cdot 17^2}$ and
   $$
   f(a,b)=\frac{a+b}{ab}+\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac{17}{2}}}{\sqrt[3]{2\cdot 17^2}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{17}}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{17}}. \tag{9}
   $$

The result $(9)$ is smaller than the result $(6)$, but is it the minimum value of $(1)$ for *real* numbers $a,b>0$? The answer is no. To show why, let $c:=\sqrt[3]{\frac{17}{2}}$; then, according to the results presented after Eq. $(8)$, $a+b=c$ and $ab=2c^2$, which imply that $a$ and $b$ are solutions to the equation
$$
t^2-ct+2c^2=0. \tag{10}
$$
However, the solutions to $(10)$ are complex:
$$
t=\frac{c\pm\sqrt{c^2-8c^2}}{2}=\frac{(1\pm i\sqrt{7})c}{2}. \tag{11}
$$
We conclude that the correct solution to the problem is the one presented by Michael Rozenberg.

---

$^{(*)}$ Minimize $f(a,b) = \frac{c^2}{17} + \frac{1}{c}$ with respect to $c=a+b$, that is, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}=\frac{2c}{17}-\frac{1}{c^2}=0$.

Comment: But, Rosenberg found $\frac5{\sqrt[3]{68}}$.

Comment: @BobDobbs, that's what I said --- see Eq. $(6)$.